# Setting label text after completing block Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, thread-safety

I want to set user name to a label because my block ("findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock") is taking time to complete and **label.text** sets **nil** .

how to set label text after completing the block??

```
class test {         

var userName: String? // variable to access user name returned by block        
private func loadData() {      

getCurrentUser()         
lblUserName.text = userName       

}    

}
```

This is the block where i am getting user data from Parse.

```
private func getCurrentUser() {         

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil { 

            currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username    
            let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")    
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentUser!)    
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (currentUsers, error) -> Void in 
                if error == nil {     
                    for user in currentUsers! {     
                       userName = user["name"] as? String      
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you still using Parse :)

Comment: yes! i am working on a project which is almost done once it will complete i will change my backend

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property observer here like this:

```
var userName: String? {
    didset {
       if let name = username {
           lblUserName.text = name
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a completion handler function argument to your getCurrentUser function and call that handler when you retrived the data:

```
private func getCurrentUser(completion: (result: String) -> Void) {         
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil { 
        currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username    
        let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")    
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentUser!)    
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (currentUsers, error) -> Void in 
            if error == nil {     
                for user in currentUsers! {     
                   completion(user["name"] as? String)     
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass the complition function like this:

```
getCurrentUser() { (result: String) in
    self.lblUserName.text = result
}
```

I cannot prove it is fully working code as I don't have XCode now to test it. But you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback which you define in the getCurrentUser function

```
private func loadData() {      

    getCurrentUser({         
        self.lblUserName.text = userName
    })

}


private func getCurrentUser(callback: () -> ()){

    // Your code

    callback()
}
```

[Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Answer (score 0):

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous call. The completion block provided to it gets executed in a separate thread once you receive a response back from server.

If you place a breakpoint in the line `getCurrentUser()` and step-in the flow, you will be able to understand the flow clearly.

There are different ways you can achieve the result,

> 1. You can set a property observer for `userName` and set the change to
>      your `lblUserName`

```
var userName: String? {
    willSet(newUserName) {
        if let username = newUserName {
            lblUserName.text = username
        }
    }
}
```

> 2. You can update the value of the `lblUserName` within your completion
>      block